# Bootstrap slider no such method 'getValue'

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

JS:

```
 // Basic Slider: Success
jQuery('#slider-success').slider({
  range: "min",
  max: 100,
  value: 60
}).on('slide', function(ev) {
    console.log($('#slider-success').slider('getValue'));
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="slider-success" class="slider-success mb20"></div>
```

I am trying to get value when the slider change dynamically. But i got an error :

Uncaught Error: no such method 'getValue' for slider widget instance

Comment: Have you imported the necessary libraries or plugins for this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to take the value from data object

`$('#slider-success').data('slider').getValue()`

Example with your code - http://jsfiddle.net/Z6CyV/66/

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
$('#slider-success').val();
```

OR

```
$('#slider-success').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#slider-success').val()` is more convenient.